# When using Conv2D in PyTorch, does padding or dilation happen first?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

Consider the following bit of code:

`torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 2, padding = 1, dilation = 2)`

Which of the following two cases is a correct interpretation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the bottom of the [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d) documentation you'll see the formula used to compute the output size of the conv layer:

[image: conv2d output shape]

Notice how `padding` is not affected by the value of `dilation`. I suppose this indicates "pad first" approach.